# How to conditional exports from package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

I have section `exports` in my `package.json`:

```
    "exports": {
        "import": "./dist/a.es.js",
        "require": "./dist/b.umd.js"
    },
```

But for development, I would like to have different path:

```
    "exports": {
        "DEV": {
            "import": "./src/a.es.js", // <---------- SRC
            "require": "./src/b.umd.js" , // <---------- SRC
        },
        "PROD": {
            "import": "./dist/a.es.js",
            "require": "./dist/b.umd.js"
        }
    },
```

Is there any way how to use some env variable?

Comment: This docs might help https://nodejs.org/api/packages.html#community-conditions-definitions

Answer (score 3):

I was able to solve this using this setup

In the package that my program imports:

```json
{
  "name": "my-special-node-package",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "production": {
        "require": "./prod/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./prod/index.esm.js"
      },
      "default": {
        "require": "./index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./index.esm.js"
      }
    },
  }
}
```

And then in my program:

```js
// index.js
const myPkg = require('my-special-node-package')
```

On production I use `node --conditions=production index.js` to execute the node program. Otherwise I use `node index.js` in dev mode.

Also, since I'm using TypeScript and since TypeScript is only really used during development time, I was able to change the default require/import values to point to a `index.ts` file.

```json
{
  // ....
  "exports": {
    ".": {
      "production": {
        "require": "./dist/index.cjs.js",
        "import": "./dist/index.esm.js"
      },
      "default": "./index.ts"
    },
  }
}
```

This setup allows for my local development to always TS files directly and not rely on each package to be built whenever it changes.